# client side people picker validation

Tags: 2013, client-object-model, people-picker

I've built my people picker using the normal method for client side:

```
// Render and initialize the client-side People Picker
function initializePeoplePicker(peoplePickerElementId) {

// Create a schema to store picker properties, and set the properties.
var schema = {};
schema['PrincipalAccountType'] = 'User,DL,SecGroup,SPGroup';
schema['SearchPrincipalSource'] = 15;
schema['ResolvePrincipalSource'] = 15;
schema['AllowMultipleValues'] = false;
schema['MaximumEntitySuggestions'] = 50;
schema['Width'] = '300px';
schema['Required'] = true;

// Render and initialize the picker. 
// Pass the ID of the DOM element that contains the picker, an array of initial
// PickerEntity objects to set the picker value, and a schema that defines
// picker properties.
this.SPClientPeoplePicker_InitStandaloneControlWrapper(peoplePickerElementId, null, schema);
 }
```

and I've set the required to true but no validation is taking place? Does this only work for server side PP controls?

S

Comment: Probably, because that validation takes place on server side if I am not wrong

Comment: yeah thought as much currently working out a way to do this client side.

Answer (score 4):

You can use javascript to validate the people picker by get all the users in that:

```
var peoplePickerElementId = "peoplePickerID"; 

var peoplePickerElement = SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict.peoplePickerID_TopSpan;
var users = peoplePickerElement.GetAllUserInfo();
if(users.length > 0)
{
    //continue;
}
else
{
    alert("Required");
}
```